How to implement SleepAPI of android in a project?
i have a College project app which focus on wellbeing, app basically need to do Sleep Tracking, play nature sounds, breath excercises, To-Do list which send notification to user and also includes brain sharpening games.
i have done its homepage in Android studio, the first feature is Sleep Tracking which i tried to implement and bombarded with Bugs, i tried multiple solutions and failed to do it, can someone tell me how to implement this SleepAPI in the correct way on the latest kotlin version?
i tried to import SleepAPI from code labs via git and run the 'start' as Codelab states to do but got many error which i failed to fix.
i want to implement this API to get sleep data like, how much user slept to display that on the sleep tab of this project.
